# Is there a word for a negative maturity

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for negative maturity?

**Context:**

The word maturity is used in a positive sense. With time comes maturity, and apparently people become better as persons. But a seasoned criminal could also say that they become mature, wherein they just became better in their own trade.

**Application example:**

Person A: Yes, I was a petty criminal in the past, but now I am mature. Hire me !!
Person B: No, what I can see is that you became more _____________, not mature. You just became a better criminal.

or

Person B: ___________ is not maturity, from what I can see, you just became a better criminal.

(of course hyperbolic example)

**Word Type:**
I think this should be either a noun or an adjective. The word mature is an adjective. The word maturity is a noun. So the word I am seeking will probably have both a noun and an adjective form accordingly.

Thank you.

Comment: Would you accept the sarcasm of *blossomed*?

Comment: I would like a word where the negativeness is more direct.

Comment: Your own word *seasoned* works pretty well for an adjective.

Comment: English scripts like strong action verbs. Not watery adjectives.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the word **hardened,** as in "a hardened criminal." [Collins defines it as:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/hardened)

> confirmed or inveterate, esp. in wrong or immoral behavior; habitual

According to Collins, this meaning is specific to American English. Of course, it doesn't imply that the criminal gained *knowledge* per se, but the word "mature" doesn't usually have that connotation either.

There isn't really an associated noun, unless you want to coin the word "hardenedness"; the gerund phrase "being hardened" is likely the best option.

Comment: Would this mean that person became a more effective and deceitful criminal capable of hiding their tracks better?

Comment: No, but "mature" doesn't really mean more skilled or effective either.

Comment: True, but I often see it used, especially by my generation (millennial or younger) in a way as if it should count as a qualification, a replacement for necessary skills. So I need to ensure that my word specifically covers skill but for negative things.

Comment: Collins doesn't say that the expression is specific to American English, just that Americans use it in the same way as the British.

Answer (score 0):

> cunning
>
> adjective
> having or showing skill in achieving one's ends by deceit or evasion. "a cunning look came into his eyes"
>
> noun skill in achieving one's ends by deceit.
> "a statesman to whom cunning had come as second nature"

(From Oxford Languages)

"cunning" seems to fit the example sentence, and it seems to match your comment of "I need to ensure that my word specifically covers skill but for negative things."

For example, you could say:

*It may look like he has washed his hands of crime and matured into a better person, but in reality, he has just become far more cunning.*

In this instance, it implies that rather than no long committing crime, he just no longer gets caught committing crime because he is more skillful/deceitful than before.

Answer (score -1):

**sketchy**.

> Louche is less common in speech than in writing. What is common, at least in the United States in recent years among people under, say, 35, is a newish usage of sketchy to mean . . . well, louche. Most of the major dictionaries* define sketchy only the way I learned it and still use it: rough, incomplete, “resembling a sketch.” But as linguist Mark Liberman wrote in Language Log earlier this year, sketchy has acquired the additional—or perhaps replacement—meaning of “questionable, iffy, untrustworthy, unsafe, poor quality, creepy, deprecated.” Examples include “a sketchy neighborhood” and “a sketchy driving record.” (Louche, by contrast, is generally used only to describe people.)
> https://nancyfriedman.typepad.com/away_with_words/2010/06/word-of-the-week-louche.html

.......

> **sketchy** adjective
> 1: of the nature of a sketch : roughly outlined
> 2 : wanting in completeness, clearness, or substance
> : SLIGHT, SUPERFICIAL
> the details are sketchy
> 3 : QUESTIONABLE, IFFY
> got into a sketchy situation
> a sketchy character
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sketchy

Comment: Do people get more sketchy as they get older? I'm struggling to see how this relates to maturity, maybe add an explanation of how it answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

The previous answers address the specific case of criminal skill, but there is a broader case of continued experience making a person worse. For example

- [fossilized](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fossilized)

is used especially when the continued experience makes the person *incapable* of the change needed for true maturity.

There are other words, like [outmoded](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/outmoded) and [antiquated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antiquated), describing consequences of continued experience—age, in fact—but they don't capture quite so well the idea that maturity requires an ability to learn and adapt.